# searchBarController doesn't follow the text when searching, cancel doesn't work like it should

Tags: swift, uisearchbar

I followed [this](http://www.appcoda.com/custom-search-bar-tutorial/) tutorial to create a custom searchbar however I'm running into a couple problems. When I type text in the search bar and I'm going past the with of the textbox the text just disappears it doesn't follow the pointer like it should.

The second problem I'm having is that the cancel button doesn't function as it should, I have to following piece of code in my CustomSearchController class

```
    func searchBarCancelButtonClicked(searchBar: UISearchBar) {
    customSearchBar.resignFirstResponder()
    customDelegate.didTapOnCancelButton()
}
```

but when the cancel button is tapped the text remains in the search bar

Does anyone know where I'm going wrong or what I could do to fix those issues.

EDIT: Alright the first problem seems be on in the font size of the search text box. I set it to 20 but anything above 18 it will stop following the text. How could I fix this. The code below shows how I set the customSearchController

```
customSearchController = CustomSearchController(searchResultsController: self, searchBarFrame: CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, tblSearchResults.frame.size.width, 100.0), searchBarFont: UIFont(name: "Futura", size: 20)!, searchBarTextColor: UIColor.greenColor(), searchBarTintColor: UIColor.blackColor())
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to do it as following. You should get some idea about how it works. I assume that your UI controller is the table one:

```
public class YourController: UITableViewController, UISearchBarDelegate, UISearchResultsUpdating {


private var searchController: UISearchController?   // your search controller


override public func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()


    // create search controller

    self.searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
    self.searchController!.searchResultsUpdater = self
    self.searchController!.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
    self.searchController!.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = false
    self.searchController!.searchBar.delegate = self
    self.searchController!.searchBar.returnKeyType = .Done
    self.searchController!.searchBar.enablesReturnKeyAutomatically = true
    self.searchController!.searchBar.sizeToFit()
    self.searchController!.searchBar.searchBarStyle = .Minimal
    self.tableView.tableHeaderView = self.searchController!.searchBar    // add search bar to table header

}


public func updateSearchResultsForSearchController(searchController: UISearchController) {
    // called after the user enters some text into the search bar
    if let searchString = searchController.searchBar.text?.stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet(NSCharacterSet.whitespaceCharacterSet()) where !searchString.isEmpty {

       // you should filter the table array here and load your table with those data
    }
    self.tableView.reloadData() // reload your table
}


public func searchBarSearchButtonClicked(searchBar: UISearchBar) {
    // some action after user clicks on the return button if needed 
}

public func searchBarCancelButtonClicked(searchBar: UISearchBar) {
    // search canceled -> you should add all the objects back here to the Table Array
}


public func searchBar(searchBar: UISearchBar, selectedScopeButtonIndexDidChange selectedScope: Int) {
    self.updateSearchResultsForSearchController(self.searchController!)
}
```

}

Or you can maybe get some idea by looking at this:
[Some Github example](https://github.com/LubosPlavucha/CocoaSmack/blob/master/classes/controllers/SimpleListSelectionController.swift)

Comment: I found where the problem of not following the text resigns see my edit maybe you know what is causing this and how it can be fixed

Comment: I don't think you need to call  customSearchBar.resignFirstResponder(). And what is the second method doing - customDelegate.didTapOnCancelButton()  ? Basically, you just should load your table array with all the values in this method. This method is called once the user cancels the filtering/searching. That means you need to bring your table to the default state loaded with all the values.